# L'hospital - Which variable does one choose?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

This comes up in solving $\int_{0}^{a}e^xdx$ which obviously is $e^{a}-1$, but the exercise is to use Riemann Sums. I get this expression

$$\frac{a}{n}\left(\frac{e^{a+\frac{a}{n}}-1}{e^{\frac{a}{n}}-1}\right)$$
which is the result of the geometric series of the Riemann Sum. Therefore, if we look at the limit, we know the solution $$ \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{a}{n}\left(\frac{e^{a+\frac{a}{n}}-1}{e^{\frac{a}{n}}-1}\right)=e^{a}-1$$
but I want to know how I would evaluate the limit without knowing it beforehand. So I'd use L'hospital, by bringing it into the appropriate form.

**But are not all the variables constants? Surely, $a$ is and $n$ is the variable that tells us how many partitions of the interval there are.**

**Do we just treat this as a function of $n\quad$ $f(n)$, where previously it was dependent on $x$?**

**Do we in general always differentiate in respect to the variable that moves to a value in the limit ( in this case $n$ )?**

EDIT: I'd try to use L'hospital like this:

$$\frac{a}{n}\left(\frac{e^{a+\frac{a}{n}}-1}{e^{\frac{a}{n}}-1}\right)=\frac{\frac{e^{a+\frac{a}{n}}}{n}-\frac{a}{n}}{e^{\frac{a}{n}}-1}$$

which should give the indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$ for $n\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: 1) Yes, for l'hospital, you always differentiate with respect to the variable which is under the limit (in this case $n$).

Comment: 2) It is not obvious how you do l'hospital in this case at all. You need a fraction where both numerator and denomerator tend to zero. But here you have two fractions.

Comment: Now it should be $\frac{0}{0}$ and one should be able to use L'hospital. Is this correct?

Comment: yeah, thats fine. I just wanted to make sure :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think I can take it from here on out :)